# Creating a Facebook Like to access page 'Plugin'?

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-like

I am making a download page where users will be able to download songs from my site (not my FB page, rather my www.myurl.com/download page). Is it possible to create a light box with a Like button that once a user has Liked a particular Facebook page, the light box goes away and they can then access the page and download songs? I know there are Like to Download plugins out there, but I cant find one that is clean.

Now that I think about it, If there is something that does something along the lines of, if the user likes the page, it does function xyz, that would work also.

Any idea on if this is possible and if there is anything out there?

Comment: Outside of Facebook (i.e. not canvas/page tab app) you need to have the user connect to your app and ask for user_likes permission to get that info.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. ok, thank you.